# location для nginx

Tags: nginx, location

Пытаюсь настроить локейшн для определённых типов файлов, но у меня получается либо так не работает, либо иначе.
Суть в том что мне нужно сделать оба варианта доступными, а работает только один...
т.е. у меня запрашивают файл: http://site.name/Work.test.txt (иногда после txt бывает какой либо параметр типа http://site.name/Work.test.txt#qwe=rty)
Если я прописываю это правило, я могу открыть файл.

```
root /var/www;
```

```
location ~ \.test.txt {
    root /var/www/tests;
}
```

но мне тогда я получаю **404** если захожу в директорию этих файлов http://site.name/files/
правило для этой директории

```
location ~ /files/ {
    autoindex on;
}
```

я вижу все файлы, но если нажимаю на любой из них, получаю **404**.
что не так, почему? Если меняю как либо первое правло, то не могу получить файл по http://site.name/Work.test.txt = **404** но работает http://site.name/files/Work.test.txt

Полный конфиг

```
server {
    server_name site.name;
    set $base /sites/site1/www;
    root $base;
    # access_log /sites/site1/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error_script.arti.log;

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/cert/script.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/cert/script.key;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location /files/ {
        autoindex on;
    }

    location ~ \.(test.txt)$ {
        root $base/files;
    }

    location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt|webp|woff2|svg)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        access_log off;
        expires max;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    include errordocs_default;
}
```

в такой конфигурации файлы напрямую я могу смотреть, а из директории где они непосредственно находятся - нет. папка `/files`

Comment: Попробуйте первый локейшн запихнуть во второй. `location ~ /files/ { location ~ \.test.txt {...} ... } `. Вообще посмотрите как работают локейшены для понимания. Тут конкретно регулярка, совпадают обе, поэтому выбирается тот вариант, который первый, о чем написано в документации. Плюс `/files` у вас настроен на один рут, а `\.test.txt` - на совершенно другой.

Comment: если запихнуть один в другой, то 404 при запросе `http://site.name/Work.test.txt`

Comment: Выложите полный конфиг сюда. И посмотрите логи в момент ошибки, там должны быть все ответы.

Comment: а файле с ошибками пишется что директория состоит из `http://site.name/files/files/Work.test.txt`, не понимаю как это исправить